# Do powers that let me shift as reaction make me negate the triggering attack at all?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, shift

I'm playing an Avenger multi-classed Ranger, and I got powers like Snarling Wolf Stance, Vengeful Parry and Fox's Cunning.

Can I use the shift granted by those powers to negate the triggering attack by moving out of the melee range of the attacking enemy, or I do my action only AFTER the attack has been resolved (and the damage has been rolled)?
I'm a bit confused because in my language (Italian) the wording is unclear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, powers that let you shift as an REACTION don't negate attacks.

There are two different kind of immediate actions: Immediate Reactions and Immediate Interrupt.

1. Immediate Reactions powers happpen AFTER the action that triggert it has been resolved.
2. Immediate Interrupt powers occur BEFORE the action that triggers the power.

When you are attacked and use an Immediate Reaction you resolve the attack first and then the Immediate Reaction.

When you are attacked and use an Immediate Interrupt you resolve the Immediate Interrupt first and attack later. Now you might not be a valid target anymore or your AC/NAD is to high so now the attack might miss.

Snarling Wolf Stance: Reaction, so happens after you have been hit or missed.

Vengeful Parry: Interrupt, BUT you have to slide the enemy adjacent so this won't get you out of melee range.

Fox's Cunning: Reaction, this happens after you have been hit or missed. You can shift and MELEE attack him back, so shift adjacent to him or you have to have reach when you shift away.

Comment: Many thanks for the excellent answer! I just have one more question. On PHB on page 219 I found a rule about forced movement stating that I can decide not to force move my opponent, and so the state "shift the enemy in a square adjacent to you" only applies if I decide to move the enemy at all. If I am correct, I am allowed to "dodge" an incoming blow by shifting back and not moving my enemy?

Comment: hmmm, good question. After looking at the forced movement glossary at the online dnd tools I found this:  "When a destination is specified, it is absolute; the creature or effect must either move the target to that destination or NOT MOVE IT AT ALL. For instance, a character’s power might say, “You slide the target up to 5 squares to a square adjacent to you,” which means the character CAN move the target up to 5 squares but only if the move ends in a square adjacent to that character."

Comment: I think Vengeful Parry might not work quite like that. "*Trigger:* An enemy adjacent to you hits or misses you. *Effect:* The target takes a -2 penalty to the attack roll. Then make the attack against the target." That says to me "enemy completes its attack first (with a penalty), then you counterattack." The Interrupt part is for applying the penalty to the attack.

Comment: So if I not move the target at all I can just shift back?
@Mike: but if my power has to be completely done before he could resume the triggering action, the attack and the shifht would be in I think, even if I'm uncertain. What do you think about that Tjnkwan?

Comment: @cesare Why would your Interrupt power have to be completely done? It's perfectly capable of saying "do this, and after the trigger is done, also do that," which it seems to be doing in slightly less explicit language.

Comment: Straight from the compendium: "An immediate interrupt jumps in when its trigger occurs, taking place BEFORE the trigger finishes. If an interrupt invalidates a triggering action, the triggering action is lost." The power doesn't say that some of it happens before and some of it happens after the trigger, therefor I think it is clear that the whole action happens before the triggering attack.

Comment: Example: An enemy makes a melee attack against Keira the rogue, but Keira uses a power that lets her shift away as an immediate interrupt. If the enemy can no longer reach her, its attack action is lost. Similarly, Albanon the wizard might use shield in response to being hit and turn that hit into a miss, or Keira might use the immediate interrupt heroic escape to evade an enemy’s attack before it can deal damage.